# How to manage projects that built on .net 4.7, ef 6 and .net core 3.1 with ef core 3.1?

Tags: .net-core, webforms, entity-framework-6, ef-core-3.1

I have two WebForm projects built on top of framework 4.7. One application responsible for sign-in /creation of accounts/etc.., another one is CRM. Developers used DB first approach by creating edmx file in both of these projects.

I was asked to build MVC app on top of dotnet core 3.1 that should utilize sign-in application and also it will be using DB for CRM.

So here are at least two areas i try to understand:

- Can .net 4.7 project depend on the project that utilize EF Core 3.1?
- Can i utilize authentication methods of the library built on top of .net core 3.1 (with ef-core 3.1) from .net 4.7 project?

Here is projects dependencies:
*Dependence from WebForm project to Authentication library is necessary because inside of CRM there is an ability to create aspnet user account.*
[image: dependencies]

If you have ideas please let me know. I'm stuck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions, no a full framework project cannot depend upon a .net core project.

If you have shared code between full framework and .net core projects you should use .net standard libraries, they can be shared across the .net platform.

You can share and use entity framework core code between the full framework and .net core projects by using it in a .net standard library. It is possible to use EF core with the full framework (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/platforms/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Well, .net core 3.1 doesn't support .net standard 2.0, and .net framework 4.7 can only depends on libraries built on .net standard <= 2.0. So we need to rewrite the webform project. And after that upgrade to .net core 3.1. Moving MVC to .net core looks like not to hard.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we decided to stay in .net 4.7. We will update to .net core, when webforms project will be rewritten.